# Hide android activity

Tags: android, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm developing a phone call's app in react native using react-native-fcm to notify the user when theres incoming calls. This is how I the app upon the receive of a notification.

```
    Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.myApp");

    startActivity(launchIntent);
```

Everything fine till now , but I want my activity to start on the background and not show any visual information about it. I can do this in MainActivity with `moveTaskToBack(true);` but it flickers by 1 second, any way to do this without flickering ?

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm

Comment: Yes Im using , react-native-fcm.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using an Activity?  If you want to run in the background, use a Service.  If that later needs to show a UI, then you launch an Activity.

Comment: You can do anything in a Service you can in an Activity, except show a UI (and even that can be worked around).

Answer (score 0):

Since you just want to show notifications from a firebase service. Look at your manifest file:

```
<service android:name=".YourFirebaseMessagingService" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
  <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
  </intent-filter>
</service>
```

The service has an intent filter with the `com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT` action, you then just need to implement the service by extending [FirebaseMessagingService](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessagingService) and overwrite the `onMessageReceived` method.

Note that `onMessageReceived` is provided for most message types, with the following exceptions:

**Notification messages** delivered when your app is in the background. In this case, the notification is delivered to the device’s system tray. A user tap on a notification opens the app launcher by default.

**Messages with both notification and data payload, both background and foreground**. In this case, the notification is delivered to the device’s system tray, and the data payload is delivered in the extras of the intent of your launcher Activity.

[image]

Services run on the main thread unless explicitly told otherwise. This means you can show any notification you'll like, or start a new Activity.

Here's an example of the above:

```
public class YourFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody() != null) {
            Log.e("FIREBASE", "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            //DO WHATEVER YOU NEED HERE TO DISPLAY YOUR MESSAGE OR ACTIVITY
        }
    }
}
```

Note that if you wish to wake up your background application, you will need to  perform a POST to the following URL:

`POST https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send`

And the following headers:

> **Key:** Content-Type, **Value:** application/json
>
> **Key:** Authorization, **Value:** key=`<your-server-key>`

For more information on this, check out this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711082/how-to-handle-notification-when-app-in-background-in-firebase).

Comment: the only problem is that event that trigger my application to open is in a npm package react-native-fcm how can I handle this is android files ?

Comment: @NicholasMendes Do you have a firebase service in the manifest? Like so `<service android:name="com.evollu.react.fcm.MessagingService" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">`

Comment: Updated my answer, hope it helps you.